# Used vlookup/index/match but for the lookup value in summary sheet that value is in merged cell of master sheet with multiple details

Tags: lookup

I am working in google sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KvhmG_G1vNXUGksyjOij5ijVQj_x2Fh1o22SvDUzfoo/edit?usp=sharing

This is the link of my google sheet.

In this worbook there are 3 sheets:- 1. PO Rcvd-09.12, 2. Sheet1, 3.Sheet2 ; Form  'PO Rcvd-09.12' i want to get data in 'Sheet1' in which i have used vlookup,index,match but not able to get exact details, as my lookup value is Column containig order number & condition is column containing colors in columns XS,S,M... as in 'PO Rcvd-09.12' sheet for one order number cell is merged and have multiple colors , So how to get this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Provide all the information inside the question, not as a link, Please also refer the [ask] link.

Comment: Hi, I have shared the link of my workbook in which i am working.  In this worbook there are 3 sheets:- 1. PO Rcvd-09.12, 2. Sheet1, 3.Sheet2 ; Form  'PO Rcvd-09.12' i want to get data in 'Sheet1' in which i have used vlookup,index,match but not able to get exact details, as my lookup value is Column containig order number & condition is column containing colors in columns XS,S,M... as in 'PO Rcvd-09.12' sheet for one order number cell is merged and have multiple colors , So how to get this?

Comment: If you don't use Excel, don't tag with Excel. Removing Excel tag. Also, please edit your question to provide clarification. Don't add information in comments. A question should have all the details without reading a wall of comments.